# Closures, loops, and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, closures

I've read several posts on the subject, but unfortunately struggling with my situation.

I am pulling some urls from an array of urls and then using those links to obtain (let's say) the title of the page from those subsites.  At the end I want a list of original urls and an array of titles (from the sublinks). i.e., go into a site/domain, find some links, curl those links to find page titles.

Problem is that my titleArray just returns a Promise and not the actual data. I'm totally not getting closures right and promises. Code runs in node as is. I'm using personal sites in my real code, but substituted common sites to show an example.

```
const popsicle = require('popsicle');

var sites = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.cnn.com'];

// loop through my sites (here I'm just using google and cnn as a test
for(var i=0;i<sites.length;i++) {
  // call function to pull subsites and get titles from them
  var titleArray = processSites(sites[i]);

  console.log(sites[i] + ": " + titleArray);
}

// get request on site and then get subsites
function processSites(url) {
  return popsicle.get(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      var data = res.body;

      // let's assume I get another collection of URLs
      // that I pull from the main site
      var subUrls = ['http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.espn.com'];
      var titleArray = [];
      for(var j=0;j<subUrls.length;i=j++) {
        var title = processSubSites(subUrls[j])
        titleArray.push(title);
      }
      return titleArray;
    });
}

function processSubSites(url) {

  return popsicle.get(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      var data = res.body;
      // let's say I pull the title of the site somehow
      var title = "The Title for " + url;
      console.log(title);
      return title;
    });

}
```

The result after running this is:

```
http://www.google.com: [object Promise]
http://www.cnn.com: [object Promise]
The Title for http://www.espn.com
The Title for http://www.espn.com
The Title for http://www.yahoo.com
The Title for http://www.yahoo.com
```

whereas it should be:

```
http://www.google.com: ['The Title for http://www.yahoo.com', 'The Title for http://www.espn.com']
http://www.cnn.com: ['The Title for http://www.yahoo.com', 'The Title for http://www.espn.com']
...
```

Comment: 1. Are yahoo.com and espn.com the subUrls for the mainUrls? May i suggest you to modify your question/sample with mainUrls and its corresponding subUrls and then the actual/intended result please?

2. Also are you pulling titles for the subUrls or the main ones

Comment: What is the version of nodejs that you are using. If it is something >= 7.6 you can take advantage of async and await - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Simple_example

Comment: @Jaya - sorry, I didn't use a good example here.  Really the main urls or domain level and the sub are really inside of a domain.  I'm only pulling titles from the subUrls.

Comment: @codetext - I'm at node 7.0 right now, but I will look into async and wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return normal data from inside a `Promise`. You need to return another `Promise` to make it chainable. To process multiple `Promise` objects in loop, you need to push them in an array and call `Promise.all(array)`;

```
const popsicle = require('popsicle');

var sites = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.cnn.com'];

var titleArrayPromises = [];
// loop through my sites (here I'm just using google and cnn as a test
for(var i=0;i<sites.length;i++) {
  titleArrayPromises.push(processSites(sites[i]));
}

var titleArray = [];
Promise.all(titleArrayPromises).then(function (titleArrays) {
  for(var i=0; i<titleArrays.length; i++) {
    titleArray.concat(titleArrays[i])
  }
  // You now have all the titles from your site list in the titleArray
})

function processSites(url) {
  return popsicle.get(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      var data = res.body;

      // let's assume I get another collection of URLs
      // that I pull from the main site
      var subUrls = ['http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.espn.com'];
      var titlePromiseArray = [];
      for(var j=0;j<subUrls.length;j++) {
        titlePromiseArray.push(processSubSites(subUrls[j]));
      }
      return Promise.all(titlePromiseArray);
    });
}

function processSubSites(url) {
  return popsicle.get(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      var data = res.body;
      // let's say I pull the title of the site somehow
      var title = "The Title for " + url;
      return Promise.resolve(title);
    });  
}
```